# I've found the chords to Chicago by Meg & Dia but can't figure out the theory

Tags: theory, chords, key, modulation

Chicago is one of my favourite Meg & Dia songs (RIP 2012). I've tabbed out a few of their songs and figured out their keys and such, but this one seems to be more than your standard vi-IV-I-V stuff. It goes like this:

Verse :

```
    Cmaj7 Bm Bb Am
```

Chorus:

```
    Dm7 Gm7 Cmaj7
```

-

```
    Dm7 Gm7
```

-

```
    Cmaj7 Bm Am7

    Eb D
```

Outro:

```
    Eb Dm Cm

    Fm Bb7
```

I'm 99% sure these are the chords I hear ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x9m3vzWppfc) to the song). I'm confused between the C and C minor scales, some of the chords are from these keys but others just don't seem to fit, or at least I can't make them to.

Thanks !

GST_Diandre

Answer (score 3):

You've just learned something important.  Not all the chords in a song have to fit into one scale.  And it's often pointless to MAKE them fit by inventing a constant string of mini-modulations.

Look at how those chords DO fit together.  C^, Bm, Bb, Am has a bass line that walks down.  That's a strong enough reason for the sequence.

Answer (score 3):

The 'theory' is that chords from parallel major and minor work well together. Nearly all of these chords are from C major/C minor, which bears this out - except - Bm. So, as Laurence states, not EVERY chord HAS to fit in a certain key, it's just that most times, they do.

Comment: Or even, once we're past very simple songs, most times they don't!